# Port knocking before git push

Tags: git, githooks

I currently have a VPS that I use as a git server.

This VPS is protected with **port-knocking**, which means that I have to send some packets to specific ports before I can connect to the 22 port (used for SSH).

I thought that I could set up a git **pre-push** hook, which triggers the port knocking, so that git could then connect to the server and push.

Unfortunately, this hook does not work. Here is how I did it:

`vim .git/hooks/pre-push`

```
echo "Foo"
[my port knocking command which works perfectly fine]
echo "Bar"
```

`chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push`

Neither *Foo* or *Bar* are displayed when I run **git push**. Nothing happens.

I guess that git tries to connect to the remote server ***before*** running the *pre-push* hook.

How can I run my port knocking command *before* any action ?

I'd be happy if anyone could help me with this problem :)

Comment: Why not create an alias for the push sequence `knock; push ..`. Ok so it has to have a special name such as `kpush` but...

Comment: Yes but it's not very convenient, and git hooks are done for this kind of things !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [git hook pre-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) is executed after git knows what it would push and thus after talking to the remote.

You can set `git config core.sshCommand 'knock && ssh'` to achieve what you want. For how this works see the documentation of [git config core.sshCommand](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coresshCommand) and the [environment variable GIT_SSHCOMMAND](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#git-codeGITSSHCOMMANDcode).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation ! This works very well :)